# встроенный assert не показывает ошибок, assertequal из unittest говорит об ошибке

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

```
class Pagination:

    def __init__(self, items=[], page_size=10):
        self._items = items
        self.page_size = page_size
        self._current = 0 if items == [] else 1
        self.num_pages = len(range(1, len(self._items)+1, self.page_size))
        Pagination.current = self._current


    def first_page(self):
        f_page = self._items[:self.page_size+1]
        self._current = 1
        return self

    def last_page(self):
        items = len(self._items)
        self._current = items // self.page_size + bool(items % self.page_size)
        return self

    def get_current_page(self, current=0):
        self._current += current
        return self._current

    def get_visible_items(self):
        if self._current == 0:
            return self._items
        elif self._current == self.num_pages:
            start = -(len(self._items) % self.page_size)
            return self._items[start:]
        else:
            pages = list(range(0, len(self._items), self.page_size))
            start = pages[Pagination.current - 1]
            visible_current = self._items[start:start + self.page_size]
            return visible_current

    def prev_page(self):
        if self._current == 1:
            return self.first_page()
        else:
            prev_page = self.get_current_page(-1)
            self._current = prev_page
        return self

    def next_page(self):

        if self._current == self.num_pages:
            return self.last_page()
        else:
            next_page = self.get_current_page(1)
            self._current = next_page
        return self

    def go_to_page(self, n):
        pages = list(range(1, len(self._items), self.page_size))
        if n > len(pages):
            return self.last_page()
        elif n < len(pages):
            return self.first_page()
        else:
            to_page_n = pages[n - 1]
            self._current = to_page_n
        return self

    def get_page_size(self):
        items = len(self._items)
        if self._items == [] and self.page_size == 10:
            return 0
        if self._current == self.num_pages:
            return items % self.page_size
        if self._current < self.num_pages and self.num_pages != 0:
            return self.page_size

    def get_items(self):      
        return self._items
```

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Evaluate(TestCase):
    def test_pag(self):
        import pag

        defaultPagination = pag.Pagination()
        self.assertEquals(defaultPagination.get_page_size(), 10)
```

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-6d9046559f50> in <module>
      1 e = Evaluate()
----> 2 e.test_pag()

<ipython-input-47-27a10c41b42b> in test_pag(self)
      6 
      7         defaultPagination = pag.Pagination()
----> 8         self.assertEquals(defaultPagination.get_page_size(), 10)
      9         self.assertEquals(defaultPagination.get_items(), [])
     10 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py in deprecated_func(*args, **kwargs)
   1336                 'Please use {0} instead.'.format(original_func.__name__),
   1337                 DeprecationWarning, 2)
-> 1338             return original_func(*args, **kwargs)
   1339         return deprecated_func
   1340 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py in assertEqual(self, first, second, msg)
    837         """
    838         assertion_func = self._getAssertEqualityFunc(first, second)
--> 839         assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
    840 
    841     def assertNotEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py in _baseAssertEqual(self, first, second, msg)
    830             standardMsg = '%s != %s' % _common_shorten_repr(first, second)
    831             msg = self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg)
--> 832             raise self.failureException(msg)
    833 
    834     def assertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):

AssertionError: 0 != 10
```

Comment: В get_page_size срабатывает первое условие (self._items пустой и self.page_size по-умолчанию равен 10), поэтому возвращается 0. 0 действительно не равен 10.

Comment: Простите, но  я вручную ставил в return уже 10

    ```if self._items == []: return 10 (self.page_size)```

Comment: Оставьте просто `def get_page_size(self): return 10` без всех условий и проверьте еще раз. Тест должен пройти нормально.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!!!
Переписал полностью get_visible_items, в которой дефолнтные значения проверяются вначале, а из нее уже функция get_page_size забирает значения